# How to send data from script on AWS to a (Wix) website?

Tags: python, web, request

I'm just facing an issue as I've written a code in python that is executing every minute on AWS (Amazon web server) and I want to send what's written to my Wix website. Do you have an idea of how I can deal with it?

An example could be the following one (this is just an example):

I'm executing a script in python on AWS server which returns the current hour every 10 minutes and I want to send this value to my website in order to display it on this website

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you have the python script running in AWS already, then you need some sort of endpoint on your Wix website to retrieve the request.

For Example:
yourwebsite.com/api/receive-time

And your python script would post some JSON to it like so:

```
{
   "time" : 1621712481
}
```

To make HTTP requests in Python, check out this link:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-post-requests-using-python/

Comment: Thanks for you answer Jack ! 
But how do i send the data from AWS to the website ? 
Do I need to store it somewhere and then search it from the website ? 
The issue is that I want to immediately display it on the website, when the script return something, i want this thing immediately on the website and so don't wait the website sends a request

Comment: If you want your website to immediately show something, then your website needs to make a GET request to some endpoint/API and display it in the HTML.